# TCP IP Header Malformed Packet

Tags: c, networking, tcp, ip

I am attempting to send a message using an IP Header. This is my IP Header

```
struct iphdr constructIpHeader(struct in_addr dst, char if_name[], int sockfd, int bufSzie){
    printf("constructing IP header...\n");
    struct iphdr ip_hdr;
    ip_hdr.ihl = 5;
    ip_hdr.version = 4;
    ip_hdr.tos = 0;
    ip_hdr.tot_len = htons(IPHDRSIZ + bufSzie);
    ip_hdr.id = htons(0x0400);
    ip_hdr.frag_off = htons(0x000);
    ip_hdr.ttl = 0x40;
    ip_hdr.protocol = 6;
    ip_hdr.check = 0;

    ip_hdr.saddr = get_ip_saddr(if_name, sockfd); // source ip
    ip_hdr.daddr = dst.s_addr;
    ip_hdr.check = ip_checksum(&ip_hdr, IPHDRSIZ); // checksum good
    printf("IP header complete\n");
    return ip_hdr; 
}
```

This is how I construct and send the data

```
    memset(&sk_addr,0,sk_addr_size);
    struct iphdr ip_hdr;
    ip_hdr = constructIpHeader(dst_ip, interfaceName, sockfd, strlen(buf));

    char ip_payload[IPHDRSIZ+strlen(buf)+1];
    char *ip = (char *)&ip_hdr;
    memcpy(ip_payload, ip, IPHDRSIZ);
    memcpy(&ip_payload[IPHDRSIZ], buf, strlen(buf));

    send_message(interfaceName, sk_addr, dst_mac, ip_payload, sockfd, 1, if_hwadd
```

This is what my Wireshark looks like
[image]

[image]

This is all really new to me, so any advice would be helpful. I've been digging around forums and I think I am constructing the header correctly, which is why I am confused on why the packet is malformed. I thought it could be something to do with the memcpys before I send the message, but I am not sure of another way to approach this.

Comment: Your TCP segment is what is malformed. You need to create a proper TCP header, and its checksum that includes covering the 96-bit pseudo-header.

Comment: @RonMaupin I thought wireshark is showing that I have created my header?

Comment: The IPv4 header is correct, but the payload is TCP, and TCP has its own header because it is a separate protocol. The protocol at each network layer (in your case, ethernet, IPv4, and TCP) each have their own headers. It may be simpler to start with UDP instead of TCP because it has a small header, and the checksum in its header is optional. In any case, TCP requires setting up a connection first, and that involves a three-way handshake, but UDP can just send with no connection or expectations.

Comment: @RonMaupin Do you have any recommendations on how to start UDP? Not really sure where to begin.

Comment: Start with the definition, _[RFC 768, User Datagram Protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc768)_. It is protocol 17 (TCP is protocol 6). The TCP definition is _[RFC 793, Transmission Control Protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793)_, and it is rather involved. The RFC for IPv4 is _[RFC 791, Internet Protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc791)_, and you should also be familiar with ICMP _[RFC 792, Internet Control Message Protocol](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc792)_.

Comment: @RonMaupin, Okay so I have changed `ip_hdr.protocol = 17;` and in the packet everything for UDP is being set correctly except the length. I keep getting bogus length errors. Do you have any suggestions?